# CSS clearfix hiding text in chrome / safari?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, clearfix

I have an odd problem that I'm facing. I'm using a simple CSS clearfix hack as described on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to clear floats. Code snippet:

```
*:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

However, adding the above code causes the text to be invisible in Chrome and Safari. I've tested it on several devices now and had the same results each time, but I can't figure out why this would be breaking anything. However, Firefox

You can view [the working version here](http://dev.zachwolf.com/fonts-demo/a/) and [the broken version here](http://dev.zachwolf.com/fonts-demo/b/). If you inspect page source, the only difference is the above snippet being commented out.

Screenshot of the issue http://cl.ly/image/3h1s0Q31473Q

I've spent some time looking around, but I can't find any mention of this problem anywhere else. Everything renders fine in Firefox.

Thanks in advance,

-Zach

Comment: Why are you applying the clearfix to `*`?!?!?!

Comment: @BoltClock honestly, I don't know. Maybe I was overworked when going through all this stuff. It seems like a bad idea this morning.